# Upgraded to Xcode 4 and iOS 4.3 now my app is just white

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Just upgraded from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4 and built my app, but all I see is a white window. If I minimize the app and open up the app again everything looks good.

I have also tried to just add a simple UIImageView to the window in my appdelegate but I get the same behavior.

I have also tested to just create a new test project and it works as it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I really didn't have time to investigate this, so I just created a new project and copied all files and project settings into it and rebuilt. And now it works as it should again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what the problem could be... but since you say that a new test project works perfectly, the thing I can think of is that you might need to change build/ target settings in ur project by editing your scheme.. try that out...